# How do I rename a new album in shotwell?

Tags: 11.10, home-directory, shotwell

I can't make or rename an album in Shotwell.Can anybody help me in renaming them?My
ubuntu version  is 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

Albums in Shotwell are called Events
When you import photos using shotwell your images are grouped by date they were taken, this group is called an Event.

Shotwell allow you to merge Events.  To do this, do a multiple select of all the Events you want to merge (Use Control-Click).

Right click on your multiple selection then select "Merge Events"

This will put every thing into one Event, then simply right click on the event and select Rename Event